# What trace flags are needed for detecting deadlocks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, deadlock

I am trying to get better information on deadlocks that are occurring in my DB.  After reading this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx), it's still unclear to me whether I should be using trace flag 1204, 1222 or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, set both flags: they present the information in different ways

Comment: Should I be setting both trace flags?